# The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: java, spring

[image]

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>springsecuritydemo</display-name>
<!--   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> -->
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DispatcherServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**offers-sevlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.security.web"></context:component-scan> 
   <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

   <bean name="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

what is wrong here? i cannot access home.jsp.
i am actually watching a tutorial in spring 3.0 and i have done exactly shown in video. can anyone point my mistake here?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the problem is in url pattern of servlet-mapping.

```
 <url-pattern>/DispatcherServlet</url-pattern>
```

let's say our controller is

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

when we hit some URL on our browser. the dispatcher servlet will try to map this url.

the url pattern of our serlvet currently is `/Dispatcher` which means resources are served from `{contextpath}/Dispatcher`

but when we request `http://localhost:8080/home` we are actually asking resources from `/` which is not available.
so either we need to say dispatcher servlet to serve from `/` by doing

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

our make it serve from /Dispatcher by doing `/Dispatcher/*`

E.g

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
version="3.1">
  <display-name>springsecuritydemo</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>offers</display-name>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and request it with `http://localhost:8080/Dispatcher/home`
or put just `/` to request like

```
http://localhost:8080/home
```

Comment: Excellent clarification, it did helped me

Comment: Is it required to use  http://localhost:8080/APP_NAME/Dispatcher/home where APP_NAME is ths the name of the application in project explorer?

Answer (score 6):

I had missing application context in the Tomcat Run\Debug configuration:[image]

Adding it, solved the problem and I got the right response instead of "The origin server did not find..."

Answer (score 4):

[image: Accessing webpages issues]

I added yellow highlighted package and now my view page is accessible. in eclipse when we deploy our war it only deploy those stuff mention in the deployment assessment.

We set Deployment Assessment from right click on project --> Properties --> Apply and Close....

Comment: I had a very similar problem to this, but instead of adding '/src/main/webapps', I had to add 'Maven Dependencies', and it then began to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in InteliJ. I went to: **Edit** -> **Configuration** -> **Deployment** -> **EditArtifact**:

[image]

Then there where yellow problems, I just clicked on fix two times and it works. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: How is this different from the previous Answer, Specifically@KernelMode's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to solve this problem.
1)Go to Project Explorer. Go to the target folder of your project, right-click and delete the target folder.
2)Right-click on your project, select run as Maven Build.
3)After you get Build Success on the console; right click on the project folder and select refresh.
After performing the above steps, try to run your project.Your problem should be solved now.

Answer (score 1):

I was running the project through Intellij and this got this error after I stopped the running server and restarted it. Killing all the java processes and restarting the app helped.

Answer (score 0):

org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class

here remove .class

org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
now you wont get

Comment: You have to justify why this will solve his problem.

Comment: Short answers like these are dangerous. I guess you meant to say to edit web.xml file and replace  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>  with
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

Answer (score 0):

In case of springboot app on tomcat, I needed to create an additional class as below and this worked:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent about 6 hours to solve it. I didn't find that answer for exactly my situation so maybe it could be useful for somebody.

When I created project, I pointed GroupId in pom.xml as "myproject.myapp" but I didn't create first "prime" package with that name in the project, where would be other packages inside of this main package (like /src/main/app etc). When I created prime package "myproject.myapp" and moved other packages inside of it, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Was following one of training with Spring webmvc 4.2.3, while I'm using Spring webmvc 5.2.3 they suggested to create a form

```
<form:form modelAttribute="aNewAccount" method="get" action="/accountCreated">
```

that was causing the "disclose" error.

Altered as below to make it work. Looks like method above was the culprit.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="aNewAccount" action="accountCreated.html">
```

in fact, exploring further, method="post" in form annotation would work if properly declared:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/accountCreated", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

The website was running fine then suddenly it started to display this same error 404 message (The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists), Perhaps because of switching servers back and forward from Tomcat 9 to 8 and 7

In my case, i only had to update the project which was causing this error then restart the specific tomcat version.  You may also need to Maven Clean and Maven Install after the "Maven Update Project"

[image: Select Maven Update Project][image: Update and Refresh Workspace]

Answer (score 0):

If you have error the origin "server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Then check the file position given here:

[image: Reference image]

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem within my project. Turned out my connection string had a typo and differed from the valid database auth. credentials. Dumb mistake on my part, hopefully somebody else saves time by reading this.